# C#: Does String.Format call ToString of the input?

Tags: c#, string, format

**Does String.Format run ToString?**

For example, if I have an object of a "complex" class, can I do:

```
 <i>String.Format("String rep. {0}",complexObj);</i>
```

Comment: if you have a complex class write your own ToString method for objects from this class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

How arguments are formatted:

> Format items are processed sequentially
>   from the beginning of the string. Each format item has an index that
>   corresponds to an object in the method's argument list. The Format
>   method retrieves the argument and derives its string representation as
>   follows:

- If the argument is `null`, the method inserts `String.Empty` into the result string.
- If you call the `Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])` overload and the provider parameter implements the `ICustomFormatter` interface, the argument is passed to the provider object's `ICustomFormatter.Format(String, Object, IFormatProvider)` method. If the format item includes a formatString argument, it is passed as the first argument to the method. If the `ICustomFormatter` implementation is able to provide formatting services, it returns the string representation of the argument; otherwise, it returns `null` and the next step executes.
- If the argument implements the IFormattable interface, its `IFormattable.ToString` implementation is called.
- **The argument's parameterless `ToString` method, which is either overridden or inherited from the Object class, is called**.

So yes, finally - as a fallback - the `ToString` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

All objects inherit from System.Object which has a [ToString() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) which will be used if you do not override it.  If you want a more meaningful output, you should override it.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "<Insert your output here>"
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't whether an object has a ToString method, but whether it will ve called, overridden or not, by String.Format.

Comment: Yes, my answer to his question states that exactly "which will be used if you do not override it."  I'm not sure how that is unclear.